# How to specify the version of RxJava when using RxKotlin?

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

Docs in the RxKotlin repository on GitHub doesn't specify a way to explicitly depend on the latest RxJava versionn.

If we see the `build.gradle` file of the library, it as of now uses `compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'`

But what if we want to keep up with the latest RxJava releases and not the one present in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the version of RxJava in your projects `build.gradle`.

The specified version of RxJava will be chosen (and override RxKotlin's) if you just explicitly specify it like this in Gradle/Maven:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'
}
```

This is also stated in the RxAndroid readme file.
I had a little chat with one of the contributors of the RxKotlin and he said that just like RxAndroid, they also internally use the same policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the `rxjava` version in your `build.gradle`, gradle will take the latest one defined (yours or the one of the library, depending which is the latest version).

So you can

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
}
```

or if you always want to have the most recent version

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:+'
}
```

But be aware of problems in the `rxkotlin` library if the version are not longer compatible (e.g. you stay on `rxkotlin:2.x` and `rxjava 3.x`. So it is a good way to update `rxkotlin` as well if possible.

Comment: I think it is better to use the frozen version numbers of libraries. :)

Comment: Yes, i agree. Just mentioned to give you all possibilities.